# What is the right way to say a car driver to increase Aircon temperature?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Like should i say reduce the aircon or increase the aircon or any other easier way to say this?

Use case: i get into a Uber car and its chilling cold. I want the driver to increase the temperature to make it comfortable.

The confusion for me is reducing the speed of aircon increases the temperature and vice versa.

Comment: "I'm freezing my tail off back here!"

Comment: Lol. could work :)

Comment: Check out [interpersonal.se] as well.

Comment: If you’re in the US, do not say “aircon”; we Yanks don’t know that word.

Comment: And to follow up on what Scott said, we Yanks would say "Turn the AC down" to mean raise the temperature.

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably just say "I'm a bit cold, could you turn the heat up a bit please?"

Comment: I think the OP has in mind something like summer with the taxi's air conditioner going full blast, as opposed to winter with not enough heating.

Comment: I don't see that really matters, you'd just replace "cold" with "warm" and "up" with "down", depending on the circumstances. Or you could say "the temperature" instead of "the heat", if you feel that's less specific.

Comment: Please start with *The confusion for me is reducing the speed of aircon…*

When you can explain in engineering terms what you mean by *the speed of aircon…* you will have cracked the problem, and be able to explain to the driver what you meant instead of *could you turn the heat up/make it warmer…*